# what does the error cannot open source file iostream c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

i got this error while debuging any program in c++ visual studio:  cannot open source file iostream c++ visual studio an example is this program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test;
    std:cout << "test" << "\n";
    
    if(test = 1){
        std:cout << "test well done" << "\n";
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

how should i get the source file do i have to download it i never used vs code so i dont know
if anynone knows please help me thanks

Comment: `iostream` is part of the Visual Studio product. You should not download it separately from anywhere. Did your installation work until recently? Did you do anything? You may want to reinstall Visual Studio or install the C++ package from within Visual Studio if you forgot to do that.

Comment: Based on your description I'm not convinced you have a toolchain installed. If you're using vs-code it can detect your Visual Studio toolchain if you installed it, but it doesn't sound like you did the latter. That, assuming you're even running on Windows, which you never clarified (in fact, you made no mention of your platform whatsoever, but the VIsual C++ tag strongly suggests Windows). Remember, vs-code is just a glorified editor (with a *lot* of nifty features, mostly provided by extensions). You still need a C++ compiler/linker/runtime installed to actually build C++ programs.

Comment: just for clarification im a begginer and i never used visual code studio so @user4581301

Comment: BTW, Visual c++ means `msvc`  which is Microsoft's c++ compiler and not g++  clang ...